# How to remove the number of the page in latex?

Tags: page-numbering

I am a newbie in Latex. I know there are many manuals where I can learn how to use Latex but I am facing a problem I can't manage to solve simply. The structure of my document is this:

- title page
- abstract
- table of contents

The problem is that I don't want that the abstract page to have the page number at the bottom. To do this in the title page I simply used the command `\pagestyle{empty}` . Now if I try to do the same with the abstract page it doesn't work. Here it is the code of my document:

```
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.40]{Sapienza.png}
\vspace{3em}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
%%%% here there are many sentences
\end{center}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\pagestyle{empty} %%in order to delete the number at the bottom of the page

\chapter*{Abstract}
%%sentences

\pagestyle{plain}%%to insert again the number of the page

\tableofcontents
```

The problem is that the abstract page keeps showing the page number and I can't manage to delete it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 63):

Use:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

It will remove the pagenumber on the page it's applied to.

Comment: Ok got it.. it works thank you. But, why the simple \pagestyle{empty} doesn't work?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your post.

Comment: Note that `\pagestyle{empty}` would remove it on the whole document.

Comment: `\pagestyle` doesn't have any effect on the current open page; it takes effect with the next page.  hence `\thispagestyle{...}`

Comment: Why this \thispagestyle{empty} does not work in my case? What is there a possible cause of this?

Answer (score 47):

I prefer this method:

```
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

It allows you to still have other heading elements.

Comment: `\pagenumbering{gobble}` will remove the number of page from the contents also.

Comment: This could result in problems using `hyperref`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke what kind of issues? What should I check for?

Comment: @Emadpres double defined page anchors and in consequence wrong page links. They would be reported in the `log` file.