# How to skip numbering of a specific page

Tags: numbering, page

I would like to know how to remove the numbering for a specific page.
I found several ways to do this, the simplest of which is `\thispagestyle{empty}` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111570/201720.

Now, this command does indeed hide the number of a given page, however, LaTeX still counts that page. 
To clarify what I mean, say my document contains 5 pages. What I want to do is to hide the number of page 4 PLUS have LaTeX not counting that page, such that on page 5, the number 4 shows up, not 5.

Put another way, I want the pages to be numbered as:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- no page number here
- 4

Comment: Try `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe also have a look at the answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546044/how-to-change-page-numbers-within-a-latex-document, you could probably define a "switch empty" . Might be that this is also working in case you want a number of pages without number, but you don't know the number of pages. (Note: I didn't test anything, is just a guess)

Comment: @DG' can you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin – done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decrease the page number (in addition to `\thispagestyle{empty}`) with the following command:

```
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it also be useful to have `\thispagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton – Sure, in addition to that. I thought the OP figured that out already. But I can add it, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can automate the process of removing the page on page "four":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\setpage}{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=4
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}% Reduce page number by 1
    \global\let\setpage\thepage% Update \setpage to be equivalent to \thepage
    % Also, don't print the page number
  \else
    \thepage% Default page number
  \fi
}

\fancypagestyle{skippagefour}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\setpage}% Centre page footer
}
\pagestyle{skippagefour}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```